# Hearing noisy ultrasounds when system auto mute

Tags: sound

### After last software update,I'm find a new problem:

---

When i use my speakers from jack,don't use any players - i hear when switch on auto mute,and noisy sound like ultrasound.

- First of all i tried switch off "auto mute" in alsamixer - not solved my problem.
- Then I tried to delete alsa and pulse - not solved my problem.

Comment: are your speakers particularly powerful by chance, for example routed through an AV receiver or amplifier? It's possible, if so, that you're hearing speaker hiss. If this is the case, it's nothing to do with your computer.

Comment: when I use headphones I hear the same...

Comment: I resolved my problem in that case: I always have open player and something play in that moment,but sound in that player for 0%.